# Breakpoints are completely ignored when debugging CakePHP application

Tags: php, cakephp, xdebug, zend-debugger

I'm developing in NetBeans a CakePHP application and finally managed to get it connecting to XAMPP debugging sessions (PHP 5.3.1 w/ Xdebug v2.0.6-dev).

It perfectly works when launching, it does pause the application on the first line.

However any further breakpoint I set is completely ignored. It does not break nor pause; it just runs to completion.

xdebug.extended_info is set to 1 and I tried with a barefoot php project without any framework magic and there breakepoints worked as expected.

What the hack? I would like to be able to use breakpoints in (Cake)PHP.

Comment: i am curious to see if anybody comes back with an answer for this.

Comment: me2 :) This is a major issue to me, I'm unable to debug CakePHP apps. I have the feeling it has something to do with the way Cake is including code pieces. But I'm not sure. It doesn't seem a conf issue. Would be nice to have at least a "worksforme" feedback.

Comment: Do you have triple checked that the execution flow is going to your breakpoint ?

Comment: @Luc: I tried both in controller and view code. Breakpoints in views' PHP code are also valid, isn't it?

Comment: Sound less like a programming problem to me. It's more frequently a reinstall task if you're on Windows. Anyway you haven't told us if multiple breakpoints work for other/ordinary PHP scripts. If so, then look for any funny `xdebug_disable()` thingys in Cake.

Comment: @mario: read my post, breakpoints do work in simple PHP apps. Also phpinfo tells me debug is enabled. Also CakePHP apps brake on the first line. But nowhere else after.

Comment: As per Google it's a common problem http://osdir.com/ml/CakePHP/2009-06/msg00879.html - but some suggested downgrading xdebug helped. Anyway you could still try to remove CakePHPs `xdebug_start_code_coverage(XDEBUG_CC_UNUSED | XDEBUG_CC_DEAD_CODE);` - though I'm not sured it gets activated. Otherwise try debugging with Eclipse to isolate the problem source.

Comment: @mario: thanks for pointing this our. I really wonder how this is messed up with NetBeans. Will try out once I've got home...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set the webroot correct to the cake-webroot-dir in
project-properties

Another thing, take a look here:

http://groups.google.ch/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/73bcf80a3d626c75

Comment: WoW! Project / Properties / Sources / Web Root set to app/webroot solved the issue.